# Custom navigation flexslider2 or slick slider

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, flexslider, slick.js

My project need to add title of posts to the dots navigation of slider.
How can i call dots navigation in a custom position or just make this run as dots navigation of slider?

```
            <ul class="slides">
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                    <?php the_title();?>
                </li>
                <?php endwhile;endif;wp_reset_query();?>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved , may this will help someone :)

```
<div class="flexslider-controls">
  <ol class="flex-control-nav">
    <li>Slide 1 Control</li>
    <li>Slide 2 Control</li>
    <li>Slide 3 Control</li>
    <li>Slide 4 Control</li>
  </ol>
</div>

var $flexslider = $('.flexslider');
$flexslider.flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  manualControls: ".flex-control-nav li",
  useCSS: false
});
```